# spring share view files between two projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a Spring web-MVC application. I want to share Spring view files (jsp files, css, html) between two projects. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not create maven module(s) and add as dependencies?

Comment: How can I do that? please tell more in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're familiar with [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

My recommendation is to build different modules for your applications, and a third module named e.g. *common* for your common classes & files.

The project structure could be the following:

```
/project
`-- common
`-- app1
`-- app2
```

So *app1* and *app2* would have a dependency on *common*

Please see [Maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) on how to start using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/)